# Dynamic creation of data.frame / data.table / tibble

Tags: r, data.table, dynamic-programming, tibble

I'm computing K metrics and N sessions. I need to create one data.frame or  data.table or tibble dynamically  (algorithmically) with all results accumulated - as the one shown below. In this case K is 4 and N is 2.

```
dtAllResults <- data.table(
  `Session 1 Metric 1` = strStats.res[[1]],
  `Session 1 Metric 2` = strStats.res[[2]],
  `Session 1 Metric 3` = strStats.res[[3]],
  `Session 1 Metric 4` = strStats.res[[4]],
  `Session 2 Metric 1` = strStats.res[[5]],
  `Session 2 Metric 2` = strStats.res[[6]],
  `Session 2 Metric 3` = strStats.res[[7]],
  `Session 2 Metric 4` = strStats.res[[8]]
)
```

How to do that?
I suspect it has to be done with `get`, `as.name`, `substitute`  or `quote`somehow, but whatever combination of these I tried, it did not work.

To make example reproducible, I include the code to initialize all variables:

```
set.seed(1); strStats.res <- list(); N=2; K=4;
for( i in N*K) { strStats.res[[i]] <- runif(1) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think NSE is not required at least based on your MWE. Here is an option:

```
nm <- do.call(paste, CJ(paste("Session", 1L:N), paste("Metric", 1L:K)))
setnames(as.data.table(strStats.res), nm)[]
```

output:

```
   Session 1 Metric 1 Session 1 Metric 2 Session 1 Metric 3 Session 1 Metric 4 Session 2 Metric 1 Session 2 Metric 2 Session 2 Metric 3 Session 2 Metric 4
1:          0.2655087          0.3721239          0.5728534          0.9082078          0.2016819          0.8983897          0.9446753          0.6607978
```

data:

```
set.seed(1)
strStats.res <- list()
N=2
K=4
for (i in seq_len(N*K)) { 
    strStats.res[[i]] <- runif(1) 
}
```